# how to transform object of objects to object of array of objects js

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on a `react-native` project which includes a calendar screen. I'm using `react-native calendars` agenda component for the calendar itself and a `firebase` realtime database for the project itself. I'm quite new at crating my own database so straggling to get the figure our the data structure right.
Currently, from the database, I get the data as

```
{
'2020-07-01': {time: "12:00", topic: "Type Casting in JavaScript"}
'2020-07-03': {time: "12:00", topic: "JavaScript basics"}
'2020-07-06': {time: "12:00", topic: "Parallax Scrolling"}
}
```

but rest-native calendars agenda only accepts data in a form of

```
{
'2020-07-01': [{time: "12:00", topic: "Type Casting in JavaScript"}]
'2020-07-03': [{time: "12:00", topic: "JavaScript basics"}]
'2020-07-06': [{time: "12:00", topic: "Parallax Scrolling"}]
}
```

what would be the best way to transform the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const OBJECT = {
'2020-07-01': {time: "12:00", topic: "Type Casting in JavaScript"},
'2020-07-03': {time: "12:00", topic: "JavaScript basics"},
'2020-07-06': {time: "12:00", topic: "Parallax Scrolling"},
};

console.log(
    Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(OBJECT).map(([key, val]) => [key, [val]]))
);
```

[Here is working solution](http://instacode.dev/#Y29uc3QgT0JKRUNUID0gewonMjAyMC0wNy0wMSc6IHt0aW1lOiAiMTI6MDAiLCB0b3BpYzogIlR5cGUgQ2FzdGluZyBpbiBKYXZhU2NyaXB0In0sCicyMDIwLTA3LTAzJzoge3RpbWU6ICIxMjowMCIsIHRvcGljOiAiSmF2YVNjcmlwdCBiYXNpY3MifSwKJzIwMjAtMDctMDYnOiB7dGltZTogIjEyOjAwIiwgdG9waWM6ICJQYXJhbGxheCBTY3JvbGxpbmcifSwKfTsKCmNvbnNvbGUubG9nKAoJT2JqZWN0LmZyb21FbnRyaWVzKE9iamVjdC5lbnRyaWVzKE9CSkVDVCkubWFwKChba2V5LCB2YWxdKSA9PiBba2V5LCBbdmFsXV0pKQopOw==)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
'2020-07-01': {time: "12:00", topic: "Type Casting in JavaScript"},
'2020-07-03': {time: "12:00", topic: "JavaScript basics"},
'2020-07-06': {time: "12:00", topic: "Parallax Scrolling"}
}

const transformed = {};
for (const date in obj) {
  transformed[date] = [obj[date]]
}
console.log(transformed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce`:

```js
const data = {
'2020-07-01': {time: "12:00", topic: "Type Casting in JavaScript"},
'2020-07-03': {time: "12:00", topic: "JavaScript basics"},
'2020-07-06': {time: "12:00", topic: "Parallax Scrolling"}
}

const normalized = Object.keys(data).reduce( (acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = [data[key]]
  
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(normalized)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to transform the data into the structure you need.

```js
const dataToTransform = {
'2020-07-01': {time: "12:00", topic: "Type Casting in JavaScript"},
'2020-07-03': {time: "12:00", topic: "JavaScript basics"},
'2020-07-06': {time: "12:00", topic: "Parallax Scrolling"}
}

const transformData = (input) => {
  const output = {} // object to return with transformed data
  Object.keys(input).forEach( key => {
    output[key] = [input[key]] // do whatever transformation here 
                               // for each key/value pair
  })
  return output
}

const transformedData = transformData(dataToTransform)

const pre = document.getElementById('display')
pre.textContent = JSON.stringify(transformedData)
console.log(transformedData)
```

```html
<body>
<pre id='display'>
</pre>
</body>
```

Note there are a variety of ways to implement `transformData`. This is just one example.